# Sequelize and Sequelize-Restful not responding

Tags: postgresql, rest, sequelize.js

I'm an express / SQL noob trying to build a reporting app using postgres and sequelize ORM.  To make the service more flexible I attempted to auto generate API routes with sequalize-restful-extended [(Author's Github)](https://github.com/pjanaya/sequelize-restful-extended) but can't seem to get anything back.

When I throw *http://localhost:8080/api* into Postman the API stays loading until I close the response I get a blank response from my morgan logs (::1 - - [11/Sep/2015:05:52:14 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" - - "-" ")

Any help or guidance would be throughly appreciated.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var http = require('http');
var restful   = require('sequalize-restful-extended');
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
var config    = require(__dirname + '/bin/config.json')[env];
var database = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
                host: config.host,
                port: config.port,
                logging: console.log,
                dialect: config.dialect
              });

var app = express();


// ROUTE REQUIRES
var port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

// MIDDLEWARES
app.use(logger('common'));
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));





  var categories = database.define('categories', { 
    CategoryID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      identifier: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true}
    },
    CategoryName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    Description: {
      type: Sequelize.TEXT,
      allowNull: true
    },
    Picture: {
      type: Sequelize.BLOB,
      allowNull: true
    }
  });

  var products = database.define('products', { 
    ProductID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
      identifier: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true}
    },
    ProductName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    SupplierID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    CategoryID: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    QuantityPerUnit: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: true
    },
    UnitPrice: {
      type: Sequelize.REAL,
      allowNull: true
    },
    UnitsInStock: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    UnitsOnOrder: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    ReorderLevel: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: true
    },
    Discontinued: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false
    }
  });

//FIND A PRODUCT'S CATEGORY
categories.belongsTo(products)





// RESTIFY ORM
app.use(restful(database));


// SERVER CONNECT
app.listen(port);
console.log("You're listening to http://localhost:" + port + " home of the internet's smoothest jazz and easy listening" );






// CATCH ALL FOR HTML 5 MODE (allows UI-Router driven states)
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.redirect('/#' + req.originalUrl);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following error was noticed when I tried to run your code:

```
$ node app1.js 
body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares app1.js:31:9
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option node_modules/body-parser/index.js:105:29
You're listening to http://localhost:8080 home of the internet's smoothest jazz and easy listening

::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2015:22:34:12 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 500 2546
TypeError: Cannot read property 'daos' of undefined
at handleIndex (/home/haris/Documents/stack-overflow/Sequelize-Restful/node_modules/sequelize-restful-extended/lib/router.js:248:48)
at Router.handleRequest (/home/haris/Documents/stack-overflow/Sequelize-Restful/node_modules/sequelize-restful-extended/lib/router.js:47:21)
at /home/haris/Documents/stack-overflow/Sequelize-Restful/node_modules/sequelize-restful-extended/lib/index.js:10:16
at multipart (/home/haris/Documents/stack-overflow/Sequelize-Restful/node_modules/sequelize-restful-extended/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/multipart.js:64:37)
...
```

and test it with 'curl -i http://localhost:8080/api'.

Going deeper I identified in `/node_modules/sequelize-restful-extended/package.json` that sequelize-restful-extended module is based on `"sequelize": "1.7.0-rc2",` devDependencie.

However in the main app `sequelize` module was installed at it's latest version 1.7.11:

```
$ npm install sequelize --save
npm WARN package.json @ No description
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @ No README data
npm WARN package.json @ No license field.
npm WARN deprecated lingo@0.0.5: This project is abandoned
sequelize@1.7.11 node_modules/sequelize
├── commander@2.1.0
├── dottie@0.1.0
├── toposort-class@0.3.1
├── generic-pool@2.0.4
├── node-uuid@1.4.3
├── validator@3.2.1
├── lingo@0.0.5
├── underscore.string@2.3.3
├── bluebird@1.0.8
├── lodash@2.4.2
├── moment@2.5.1
├── sql@0.35.0 (sliced@0.0.5, lodash@1.3.1)
└── circular-json@0.1.6 (wru@0.2.7)

$ cat package.json 
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.3",
    "epilogue": "^0.6.1",
    "express": "~4.13.3",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "path": "~0.11.14",
    "pg": "^4.4.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^1.7.11",
    "sequelize-restful-extended": "^0.1.4"
  }
}
```

So solution is to adjust version `sequelize`

- remove latest version of `sequelize` from main app

  ```
  $ npm uninstall sequelize
  ```
- and then install version 1.7.0-rc2 upon which sequelize-restful-extended module was dependent

  ```
  $ npm install sequelize@1.7.0-rc2 --save
  ```

At the end package.json looked as follwing:

```
$ cat package.json 
{
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.3",
    "epilogue": "^0.6.1",
    "express": "~4.13.3",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "path": "~0.11.14",
    "pg": "^4.4.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^1.7.0-rc2",
    "sequelize-restful-extended": "^0.1.4"
  }
}
```

Then app was running as expected

```
$ node app1.js 
body-parser deprecated bodyParser: use individual json/urlencoded middlewares app1.js:31:9
body-parser deprecated undefined extended: provide extended option node_modules/body-parser/index.js:105:29
You're listening to http://localhost:8080 home of the internet's smoothest jazz and easy listening
::ffff:127.0.0.1 - - [12/Sep/2015:23:02:37 +0000] "GET /api HTTP/1.1" 200 119
```

and responded as expected as well

```
$ curl -i http://localhost:8080/api
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 119
ETag: W/"77-dGBloVSmkq0I3FzWdjCdaQ"
Date: Sat, 12 Sep 2015 23:03:12 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{"status":"success","data":[{"name":"categories","tableName":"categories"},{"name":"products","tableName":"products"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, my process seems to be limited to hacking at things until they work, and if I can't find an answer on Stack Overflow directly pertaining to my issue I'm stuck.

Thank you for detailing out your error investigation process, regardless of the solution your process has helped me significantly.

Comment: Glad I could help. Would you pls. be kind and accept my answare according to: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

From what I see you have used

```
app.use(restful(database));
```

vs

```
app.configure(function() {
  app.use(restful(sequelize, { /* options */ }))
})
```

suggested by [manual](https://github.com/pjanaya/sequelize-restful-extended#usage)

could this be your problem?

Comment: Since Express 4.x app.configure() has been depreciated- [Express 4x changes](http://expressjs.com/guide/migrating-4.html#other-changes)